# select text a tag with specific attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I want to alert English texts, not digits, and wrote jQuery code that returns `<span>`s that don't have `rtl` attribute but my problem is it alerts twice for digits and English texts.

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var text = $("span:not([dir=rtl])").text();
  alert(text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <h2>Blessing upon the Bearers of the Throne</h2>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
  <p style="text-align:center">&nbsp; </p>
  <p style="text-align:center">
    <span style="font-size11pt">
        <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif">O God, as for the Bearers of Thy Throne, who never flag in glorifying Thee, </span>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p style="text-align:center">
      <span style="font-size11pt">
          <span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif">
              <span dir="rtl" lang="AR-SA" style="font-family&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;">111111111111111111111111111َ </span>
          </span>
      </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably you want to select only the innermost span without that attribute, but your current selector selects also parent spans. Have you tried something like `span:not([dir="rtl"]):not(:has(span)`?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn doesnt work can you write more clear and correct code?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cb69m3e9/ (sorry for previous typo, typed from a tablet, it seems that autocorrection spoiled it)

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr` in jQuery. This will work

you can check following Example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('dir') == 'ltr'){
         alert($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span dir="rtl">Coffee</span>
<span dir="ltr">Milk</span>
<span dir="rtl">Soda</span>
```